# how to assign catched exceptions to shared pointers in boost 1.56.0

Tags: boost, shared-ptr

`try{ boost::rethrow(excep)}`
`catch(boost::exception &e)`
{

}
How to add this e to shared pointer.This e is not in heap area .

Comment: class Exception: public virtual std::exception,public virtual boost:;exception{ }  boost::shared_ptr <exception > e_shared   . Now I need to add that e to e_shared. How its possible

Answer (score 1):

Indeed exception pointers are special: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/exception/doc/exception_ptr.html (just like the corresponding [`std::exception_ptr`][1])

There's no probem  wrapping a *copy* of the exception but

- you run into object slicing issues because there's typically no virtual cloning pattern in exception hierarchies
- it would allocate, this is usually a bad idea during exception handling (perhaps you can alleviate this with some kind of pool allocator and `allocate_shared`)
- I question the use; are you looking for [Transporting of Exceptions Between Threads](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_77_0/libs/exception/doc/tutorial_exception_ptr.html)?

That mechanism has been adopted into C++ with http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2179.html

In short I strongly think you're looking for `boost::exception_ptr` or `std::exception_ptr` with [`current_exception()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/current_exception).
[1]: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception_ptr